# Combine multiple URL parameters for search query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-query

I'have this query string `ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* {?{QueryString.Document}}` and i would like to add another `QueryString` to it but im not sure how to add it correctly.

I've tried `ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* {?{QueryString.Document}} or {?Title:{QueryString.Search}}`

`ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* {?{QueryString.Document}} {?Title:{QueryString.Search}}`

I have a document called `Test.docx`.

If my query looks like this `?Document=Guidelines&Search=Test` It works.

If my query looks like this `?Document=Guidelines&Search=Te` It doesn't work.

But it's not working. Can someone help me out?

As far as I know then `{?Title:{QueryString.Search}}` means that if the title contains search parameter.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add multiple additional query parameters. OR not "or" should be used. AND (or a space as AND is assumed in KQL) may also be used as well as "()" to enclose logical groups.

Comment: Could you throw an example at me?